# How to change one character into another character?

Tags: bash

I want to change this string:

```
At, U omz rqqx uf itqz kag'dq zqmd yq
```

into this string:

```
Oh, I can feel it when you're near me
```

it means that `a(ASCII=97)` into `o(ASCII=111)`, and so on

how can i change this string in bash scripting?

Comment: google `ROT` or `ROT13`, and implement with `tr` in linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is encrypted using a rot14 chiffre. You can use the following `tr` command to decrypt it:

```
tr '[A-Za-z]' '[O-ZA-No-za-n]' <<< "At, U omz rqqx uf itqz kag'dq zqmd yq"
```

Output:

```
Oh, I can feel it when you're near me
```

Explanation:

The input character set includes upper and lowercase ascii characters `[A-Za-z]`. You said that the chiffre `a` translates to `o`. Assuming that the string is encrypted with rot14, the same would apply to `A` and `O`. That's why the output character set starts at `O`. Once `Z` has been reached we continue at `A` until `N` (which comes before `O`). That's a forward rotation by 14. The same applies to lowercase characters.

Comment: Works perfectly! `+1`

Comment: Can you explain how the `[..a-z]` corresponds to `[..A-No-za-n]`, am at loss there.

Comment: @Inian it is on the form A->O, B->P, ..., Z->N. That is, `tr` maps every element of one list to the corresponding in the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tr` command for such a translation. `tr` accepts string describing `from` and `to` characters. In this case, it might be something like the following (I did not write the entire sequences - it is just an example):

```
echo "At, U omz rqqx uf itqz kag'dq zqmd yq" | tr "AtUo" "OhIc"
```

Comment: It produces an output as `Oh, I cmz rqqx uf ihqz kag'dq zqmd yq` on `tr (GNU coreutils) 8.4`, am I missing something here?

Comment: @Inian Yes, you are missing my comment about incomplete list.

Comment: Didn't re-collect that my bad! I did not down-vote you BTW.

Comment: @GMichael You did not solved the problem. That's why the down-vote.